# Active Record Query - Has many through association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, search, activerecord

I am trying to write active record queries in my model for an advanced search.

I have a Firms model and each firm has many Categories through Categorizations

I have the following built into my search method at the moment.

```
def find_firms
    firms = Firm.order(:name)
    firms = firms.where("name like ?", "%#{name}%") if name.present?
    firms = firms.categories.find(id: category_id) if category_id.present?
end
```

My category schema looks like this.

```
create_table "categories", :force => true do |t|
  t.text     "name"
  t.datetime "created_at", :null => false
  t.datetime "updated_at", :null => false
 end
```

and my categorizations

```
 create_table "categorizations", :force => true do |t|
   t.integer  "category_id"
   t.integer  "firm_id"
   t.datetime "created_at",  :null => false
   t.datetime "updated_at",  :null => false
 end
```

and my search form view

```
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :category_id, "Practice Area" %><br />
    <%= f.collection_select :category_id, Category.order(:name), :id, :name, include_blank: true %>
  </div>
```

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

As i keep getting the error:

```
 undefined method `categories'
```

Many thanks.

Ross

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to run the `categories` method on the array returned by `firms` which will fail. I am assuming you want to return the firms with the given category id.

```
def find_firms
  firms = Firm.order(:name)
  firms = firms.joins(:categories).
            where(:categories =>{ id : category_id}).uniq if category_id.present?
  firms = firms.where("name like ?", "%#{name}%") if name.present?
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your `find_firm` function to this:

```
 def find_firms
    if category_id.present?
      if name.present?
        Firm.where("name like ?", "%#{name}%").joins("JOIN categorizations ON firms.id = categorizations.firm_id").where("categorizations.category_id = ?", category_id).order(:name)
      else
        Firm.joins("JOIN categorizations ON firms.id = categorizations.firm_id").where("categorizations.category_id = ?", category_id).order(:name)
    elsif name.present?
      Firm.where("name like ?", "%#{name}%").order(:name)
    else
      Firm.order(:name)
    end
  end
```

Comment: Hi Eric, thanks for the reply, but it still seems to be throwing up the error: undefined method `categories'